# Recognize number on 7 segment display with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, ocr

I am trying to recognize the number on the 7 segment display.

I am using python on Jupyter notebook .

I have the 0~9 7 segment displayed number image,
and each number with . is saved seperately.
Below is the sample image of `3` ,`3.` ,`2` , `2.`

[image: 3]
[image: 3.]
[image: 2]
[image: 2.]

and I want to find these image on the target image.

[image: target image]

I heard there are tools to find similar image on `OpenCV`.

I tried **Brute-Force Matching with SIFT Descriptors and Ratio Test**
but the output does not seem accurate.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\test\\deeplearningimage\\thermo\\3..png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # trainImage
img2 = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\test\\thermosample.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)          # queryImage
# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv.SIFT_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
# BFMatcher with default params
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
# Apply ratio test
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])
# cv.drawMatchesKnn expects list of lists as matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()'
```

here is the output of the code above
[image: brute-force matching output]

Not sure how to proceed with this.
Any other `opencv` that would work for this problem?

Comment: Have you considered [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)?

Comment: @MANDU *"I want to find these image on the target image"*, you want to find the location? or whether if it exists or not?

Comment: I've successfully used the ideas from here:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/13/recognizing-digits-with-opencv-and-python/
to record digits from a 7-seg display

Comment: @SiHa anyway in that tutorial, he doesn't consider the dot. just the 7 segments right?

Comment: Now you mention it, yes I believe that is true (it's been a while).

Answer (score 2):

You can use template matching after thresholding, and edge detection
[image: Result]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# Read Image
BGR = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
RGB = cv2.cvtColor(BGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Channels split
R = BGR[...,2]
G = BGR[...,1]
B = BGR[...,0]

# Threshold per channel
R[B>120] = 0
R[G>120] = 0
R[R<230] = 0

# Binarize
Binary = cv2.threshold(R, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
# Edge Detection
Edges = cv2.Canny(Binary, 50, 200)

# Read Template
templBGR = cv2.imread('templ.png')
templRGB =  cv2.cvtColor(templBGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
templateGray =  cv2.cvtColor(templBGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Binarize Template
templateBinary = cv2.threshold(templateGray, 84, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
# Denoise Template
templateFiltered = cv2.medianBlur(templateBinary,7)
# Resize Template
template = cv2.resize(templateFiltered, (templBGR.shape[1]//2, templBGR.shape[0]//2))
# Edge Detection Template
templateEdges = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
# Extract Dimensions
h, w = template.shape

res = cv2.matchTemplate(Edges,templateEdges,cv2.TM_CCORR)

(_, _, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

img = RGB.copy()
cv2.rectangle(img, (maxLoc[0], maxLoc[1]), (maxLoc[0] + w, maxLoc[1] + h), (255,255,128), 2)

plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(RGB)
plt.title('Original')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(Edges, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Segmented')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(templRGB)
plt.title('Template')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('Result')
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

if you want to do **multi-matching** better to use a **loop**:

```py
threshold = 0.8
Loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*Loc):
    cv2.rectangle(img, (Loc[0], Loc[1]), (Loc[0] + w, Loc[1] + h), (255,255,128), 2)
```